# View source code of built in function from inside Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to view the source code of a built-in function directly from visual studio 2017?
For example if I want to view the source code of the `WriteLine` function, I selected it, right clicked it, and when I pressed on `Go To Implementation`, it gave me this message:
[image]

Comment: For .NET Framework you can look at source but not from within VS - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I know I can always search it online, what I want is to do it directly from the visual studio if possible

Comment: I believe you can do that with the Resharper extension

Answer (score 1):

în Call stack you can choose something like "Show External Code", should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are the .pdb files. Every .dll needs a corresponding .pdb file that maps the .dll to the source code. For your example, System.Console, you need the .pdb file for mscorlib.

The following pages show how to load this pdb file
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/166c70e7-9e39-44bf-8e08-76231e59ec34/mscorlibpdb-not-loaded?forum=visualstudiogeneral
["mscorlib.pdb not loaded" yet the mscorlib.dll is NOT missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985217/mscorlib-pdb-not-loaded-yet-the-mscorlib-dll-is-not-missing)

Optionally, if you feel risky enough, you can download the the c# project and try to compile the .pdb file your self
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html