# where is Web Site Administration on visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2015, website-admin-tool

I cannot found Web Site Administration Tool in visual studio 2015.
where is it?

It used to be on menu "website > Administration Tool" or "Project > Administration tool" but is not anymore.

Comment: [Thinktecture.IdentityManager as a replacement for the ASP.NET WebSite Administration tool](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx)

Comment: On visual studio 2012
Try:  project-> ASP.NET Configuration 
http://rion.io/2013/03/26/finding-the-asp-net-configuration-tool-in-visual-studio-2012/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. You can get to it via IIS or as I did, I copy it to a development folder for future use. Here are two options...

**1. Launch the Web Site Admin Tool using a command window:**

1. Open a Command Window running it as a Admin
2. Change the folder to IIS Express:
   `cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express\`
3. Run the following command to start up IIS Express:

`iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles" /port:8082 /clr:4.0 /ntlm`

4. Access the Admin Site via the following URL:
   http://localhost:8082/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:[YOUR SITE PATH HERE]\&applicationUrl=/

**2. Launch the Web Site Admin Tool using IIS:**  You can try running the site from the Windows folder but after a couple of issues I just moved it to another folder.  The steps below cover that process.

- Copy the Admin Site from the following folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles
- Change the web.config to allow any user to access the site
- Setup the site in IIS. Set the Authentication as shown below.  Use the following URL to manage your ASP.NET site.
- http://localhost/ASPNetAdmin/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:[YOUR SITE PATH HERE]\&applicationUrl=/

[See the following post at this link](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2014/06/22/asp-net-web-site-administration-tool-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: This worked, but with one change. I had to NOT run the command windows as an administrator. Please reference [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391767/access-to-the-path-c-windows-microsoft-net-framework-v1-1-4322-temporary-asp-n/38933958#comment66088843_38933958)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the port that you have configured in your app,

My command:

iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles" /port:58835 /clr:4.0

Also there's a video search for "How to access ASP .Net Web Site Configuration Tool using Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0):

I was starting out brand new without a web.config file set up. This is what I did.

(You must have a local sql server running for this)
Register your sql server with asp.net:

1. Open a command prompt and change directory to .net

```
cd  <windowsDirectory>\Microsoft.Net\Framework\<version>\
```

2. Type aspnet_regsql
3. Go through wizard to set up your database
4. Go to your website project and edit your web.config file
5. Add these configurations, updating them for your userid, password, etc.

```
        <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

6. Open a Command Window
7. Change the folder to IIS Express: cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express\
8. Run the following command to start up IIS Express:

```
iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles" /port:8082 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

9. Access the Admin Site via the following URL

```
 http://localhost:8082/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:[YOURSITEPATHHERE]\&applicationUrl=/
```