# How to launch the Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT) for an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, wsat

Is it possible to launch the WSAT when your web site is hosted in Azure as an App Service?

I'm trying to manage users and roles in the ASP.NET membership system (SQL based). According to this MSDN article (link below), you launch WSAT from Visual Studio. I gather this would only work if VS was installed on the same machine as IIS. There is no mention of WSAT in relation to an Azure App Service. There is no such option in my Visual Studio 2015 (yes, I converted my project to a web site). It seems like I should be able to launch WSAT from the Azure Portal, but I cannot find it there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx
How to Access the Web Site Administration Tool
To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click ASP.Net Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[where is Web Site Administration on visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194465/where-is-web-site-administration-on-visual-studio-2015)

1. Launch the Web Site Admin Tool using a command window:
   •   Open a Command Window running it as a Admin
   •   Change the folder to IIS Express cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express\ Run the following command to start up IIS Express iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles" /port:8082 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
   •   Access the Admin Site via the following URL:http://localhost:8082/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:[YOUR SITE PATH HERE]\&applicationUrl=/