# Accessing ...hash is denied

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

I use the **ASP.NET Web Administration tool** for setting website security.

When I click the security tab I get the following error -

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\root\6f3ff33a\4362990a\hash' is denied.
```

What would be the reason for this error ?

Comment: may this help https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH13388.html

Answer (score 1):

The IIS User does not have access to the solution folder. So give `everyone` or at least the `IIS User` full read/write access.

There is another suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391774/2768231) to reinstall the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I received this error because I forgot to start AND build the web application using administrator rights.

To have Visual Studio start with aministrator rights by default, see

[How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default)